# taxonomy_node_get_terms(arg(1)) kills layout in page.tpl.php

Tags: nodes, 7

I use this function to get the node's taxonomy term.

```
$tax = taxonomy_node_get_terms(arg(1));
```

Calling this function destroys the layout of the page. Why?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. Clive's answer explain which argument needs to be passed to `taxonomy_node_get_terms()` in Drupal 6. If there is something else that is wrong in your code, you need to show the code used in page.tpl.php.

Answer (score 1):

[`taxonomy_node_get_terms()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_node_get_terms/6) needs a node object as the first argument; [`arg()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/arg/6) returns a part of the URL (which is just a string).

You can use the [`menu_get_object()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/6) function to get the current node (if available) so it would be easier to use that:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if ($node) {
  $tax = taxonomy_node_get_terms($node);
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same result, if I use your function. The page gets not rendered properly if I use the function   `taxonomy_node_get_terms()`....I use the function in the main template (page.tpl.php)

Comment: @Lars without seeing what you are using in your page.tpl.php file, it is not possible to tell you what it is wrong. Considering the code you are showing in your question, I would suggest you to accept this answer, or expand the question to show what code is used in the page.tpl.php file.